# How do you apply a material to a specific set of faces on an object in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, selection-tools

I created this cube with the letter "R" cut into it with a mesh boolean node. I want to apply material to a specific part of the letter "R" as marked in blue. I tried using the index node with a compare node but the selection is erratic.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one possible way is to add an icosphere and then you can determine the color by the proximity node like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow!! This community never ceases to amaze me! Thank you so much!

Comment: i don't want to take your enthusiasm...but there will be a point of disappointment if you ever have contact to the moderators...you will see.